# Gradle - add applicationIdSuffix depending on buildType for a specific productFlavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-type

In an Android (Java/Gradle/Android Studio) application, I am trying to achieve setting an applicationIdSuffix (".dev") for my debug builds, but ONLY for a specific product flavor (let's say flavorA). For example what I want is:

```
flavorA release id -> com.company.flavorA
flavorA debug id -> com.company.flavorA.dev
flavorB release id -> com.company.flavorB
flavorB debug id -> com.company.flavorB
```

I do know how to set the .dev suffix in all flavors in the buildTypes debug block, and I have set some buildConfigField values that depend on both flavors and buildTypes via an `applicationVariants.all { variant -> () }` loop. I have not yet managed to use this loop for setting an applicationIdSuffix.

I have also tried adding `productFlavors.flavorA.applicationIdSuffix ".dev"` in the debug buildType block, but for some reason it is also applied to the release build - which I find quite strange.

Lastly,

```
flavorA {
   applicationIdSuffix = [debug: ".dev"]
}
```

also doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way I can get the behavior I want?

Comment: why `flavorB debug id -> com.company.flavorB` not `flavorB debug id -> com.company.flavorB.dev` ? ... then you could just add `applicationIdSuffix ".dev"` inside `buildTypes.debug`

Comment: @Selvin I want to keep the same package name for this flavor because of server issues. This behavior might change in the backend eventually, if no workaround is found, but for now this is how we want it, if possible.